# Extract naclports compiled libs from nacl sdk

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-nativeclient

I have to develop in a windows environment. Unfortunately naclports was not able to compile libs on windows therefore i had to do that on a linux machine. Now i have a shared folder nacl_sdk_linux and am wondering how to extract the compiled libs and copy them to my windows nacl_sdk?

Answer (score 0):

Native Client compiled files are the same on every OS, so you should just be able to copy any object/bitcode, archive, or shared library file built on Linux to a Windows machine and use it. If you have a whole directory you can probably just copy that.

Comment: but how do i know which files belong to the shared libs ?

Comment: Sorry, that also applies to shared libs if you are using the glibc toolchain. So if you have libfoo.so built on Linux you can use it on Windows.